# Cannot open Excel.Application workbook

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

This is from a macro in Word that accesses an Excel workbook:

```
Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook

ExcelFilename = CurDir() & "\" & ThisDocument.CustomDocumentProperties("Source")

'This tests if ExcelFilename is a valid file:
If Dir(ExcelFilename) = "" Then  Stop

Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilename)
```

It worked until today. Now, the last line gives me a Runtime Error 9: "Subscript out of Range"

That sounds like what would happen if ExcelFilename was an invalid file, but the Dir function confirms that it's not.

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like "Source" property value is not correct excel file name string. What is the value of "Source" property?

Comment: Your question made me realize I'm capturing the field itself, NOT the value! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

PanjakR's comment made me realize that should change this:

```
ExcelFilename = CurDir() & "\" & ThisDocument.CustomDocumentProperties("Source")
```

to this:

```
ExcelFilename = CurDir() & "\" & ThisDocument.CustomDocumentProperties("Source").Value
```

I wish I knew why my Dir statement didn't flag it, but that's not important. Thanks, PanjakR.